# Filtering Django Query on Date

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

This is probably an easy one, but I don't know enough Python to know what solution to search for.  I have a large database of records I need to query and then filter by year and day of week.  Below is my code.  Thank you for your help.

View

```
totals = Traffic.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('sessions'), Sum('new_users'), Sum('reminder'), Sum('campaigns'), Sum('new_sales'), Sum('sales_renewals'))

total_sessions_2014_m = totals.get('sessions__sum').filter(created__year=2014, created__day="Monday") {# My attempt to filter #}
```

Template

```
{{ total_sessions_2014_m }}
```

I'm using the DateField for my `created` model object.

I am getting an error in the browser - 'int' object has no attribute 'filter'

There error says it all, but I just can't wrap my mind around it.

Comment: I'm guessing you're trying to filter a single sum, try filtering before you sum

Comment: I was trying to inherit from the totals aggregate, but decided to bench that for now.  I was able to get filtering working for year like this `total_sessions_2014_m = Traffic.objects.filter(created__year=2014).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))` but when I add `created__day="Monday"` I get the error invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Monday' in the browser.  I am guessing because I need to convert the day to a string with `strftime("%A")` but thats just me guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it with `total_sessions_2014_m = Traffic.objects.filter(created__year='2014', created__week_day=2).aggregate(Sum('sessions'))`

It was the `created__week_day=2` that did the trick.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week-day